# Hibernate batch insert into unidirectional one-to-many collection

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, batch-processing

I have an `ItemList` class containing a set of `Items` mapped like this:

```
<class name="ItemList">
   <id name="PID" column="PID">
      <generator class="uuid" />
   </id>
   <version name="Version" />
   <set cascaed="save-update" name="Items">
      <key column="itemlist_id" />
      <one-to-many class="Item" />
   </set>
</class>

<class name="Item">
   <id name="PID" column="PID">
      <generator class="uuid" />
   </id>
   ...
</class>
```

This is a unidirectional association. I need to batch insert 1000s of `Items` into an `ItemList`. Using the hibernate doc on batch inserts, I have something like this:

```
ItemList itemList = ...

int i = 0;
for (Item item : someItems) {
    // .. some processing..

    itemList.getItems().add(item);

    if (++i % 30 == 0) {
       session.update(itemList);
       session.flush();
       session.clear();
    }
}
```

There are clearly some problems with. At each flush, 30 Items are inserted. Then the version of ItemList is updated. Then all 30 Items are updated with the PID of ItemList.

1. How can I avoid incrementing the ItemList version after each batch?
2. How can I avoid the 30 updates?

Answer (score 0):

1. Sorry, can't help you with that (but why do you care?).
2. You mean the update every 30 items? You don't want too... unless you're willing to risk running out of memory, as all thousand `Item`s are stored in the session-level cache.
3. It works because, as [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#flush%28%29) of `Session.flush()` states:

> *Flushing* is the process of synchronizing the underlying persistent
>   store with persistable state held in memory.

So after flushing you're done and good with the last 30 items, they're on the DB side. **However**, it doesn't mean that they're *committed*. The DB knows you're in a middle of a transaction that wasn't yet committed.

**EDIT**

Maybe I realize now why the version is incremented after each `flush`. I'm speculating here. Hibernate uses the `version` column in order to verify that, since the transaction has started, no other transaction has changed the entity that was modified by the current transaction. But this verification is done solely on Hibernate's behalf, not using any DB inherent functionality for that. I assume this is true because the DDL of the version tables shows the `version` column is a plain `int` (it also makes sense since Hibernate is a cross-DB-vendors API but OTOH they could have specific tooling for each vendor). So, just before flushing, Hibernate has its last chance to verify that the flushed entities aren't stale data. After flushing, these updated entities aren't marked anymore for update so that future flushes, even in the same transaction, will not fire a version verification event.

Comment: (1) Because all the inserts are only one operation and the version should reflect that. (2) After the 30 items are inserted, 30 UPDATE statements run. I'm trying to avoid those. (3) My last question was unclear but I think I figured it out.

Comment: (1) I edited the answer so it tries to explain why it isn't possible. (2) I'm surprised of that... I have no answer for that, nor I understand why couldn't Hibernate possibly make that optimization automatically. (3) great.

Comment: and (1) `version` isn't supposed to reflect that since its designated for optimistic lock concurrency control. So it doesn't necessarily reflect _transactions_.